# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'req.body' as it is undefined. (Setting up MERN authentication)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am very new to Backend and MERN. I apologize for any misuse of the vernacular.
I am trying to set up a basic **authentication with MERN** and **Insomnia** as the **REST API CLIENT**. **The server runs fine being initiated with npm run dev as I have written it in the script**. I am also utilizing **nodemon**, **jwb**, **bcryptjs**, **mongoose**, and **dotenv** as dependencies.

Posting a register request works perfectly fine: [Insomnia Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VirqJ.jpg)

But posting a login request like this: [Insomnia Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA7KQ.jpg) results in an error when destructuring the req.body in my router as shown here: `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'req.body' as it is undefined. at C:\Users\mackm\Desktop\Folders 2\vscode_work\React Projects\AUTHMERN\routers\userRouter.js:65:13`

**server.js** file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

//set up server

const app = express();
PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port: ${PORT}`));

//reads header of requests, if so: parses the json text into object and puts into request.body
app.use(express.json());

// connect to mongodb server

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MDB_CONNECT,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },
  (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  }
);

//set up routes

app.use("/auth", require("./routers/userRouter"));
```

routers/**userRouter.js**:

````
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

//register

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password, passwordVerify } = req.body;

    //validation

    if (!email || !password || !passwordVerify)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Please enter all required fields" });
    if (password.length < 6)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Please enter password of 6 or more charac" });
    if (passwordVerify !== password)
      return res.status(400).json({ errorMessage: "Passwords have to match" });
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });

    // Check for existing users

    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errorMessage: "An account with this email already exists.",
      });
    }

    // hash the password

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    //save a new user account to the database
    const newUser = new User({
      email,
      passwordHash,
    });

    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    //sign the token
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        user: savedUser._id,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );
    //send the token in an HTTP only cookie
    res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true }).send();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send;
  }
});

// log in
router.post("/login", async (res, req) => {
  try {
    console.log("login initiated");
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    //validate
    if (!email || !password)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Please enter all required fields" });
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    //handle non existent account
    if (!existingUser)
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Incorrect email or password" });
    const passwordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
      password,
      existingUser.passwordHash
    );
    //match password
    if (!passwordCorrect)
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Incorrect email or password" });
    //sign token
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        user: existingUser._id,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );
    //send the token in an HTTP only cookie
    res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true }).send();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});

module.exports = router;```
````

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved:

In **userRouter.js**
**Incorrect (Original)**:

```
router.post("/login", async (res, req) => {
```

**Correct (Fixed)**:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
```

Parameters of arrow function originally in reverse of the intended code

Answer (score 1):

You could use the body-parser module to use req.body and it's properties easily

```
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

/*assuming an express app is declared here*/
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Then if you use `req.body` you will find the contents of the request.